# Sobolev function and polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded open set with Lipschitz boundary. Let $v\in H^{l+1}(\Omega)$. I have to prove that

*There exists a unique $p\in\mathbb{P}_l$ such that
$$
\int_\Omega D^\alpha v=-\int_\Omega D^\alpha p
$$
for every $|\alpha|\le l$*, *where $\mathbb{P}_l$ is the space of real polynomials defined on $\Omega$ and of degree less or equal to $l$.*

Do you have any ideas?

P.S. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: It would improve your Question if you expressed your own thoughts about the problem and how to attack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$ p(x) = \sum_{|\beta|\leq l} c_\beta x^\beta $$
for some coefficients $c_\alpha$, which you have to find based on the system of equations 
$$\int_\Omega D^\alpha p=\sum_{|\beta|\leq l,|\beta|\geq|\alpha|}c_\beta D^\alpha x^{\beta} = -\int_\Omega D^\alpha v,\qquad \forall \ |\alpha|\leq l.$$ 
The uniqueness comes from the fact this is a tri-diagonal system. In other words, you can solve the coefficients $c_\beta$ for the highest order $x^{\beta}$ first for $|\beta|=l$, and then the coefficients $c_\beta$
for $|\beta|=l-1$, etc.